# How to create an SSLContext that will trust no server certificates?

Tags: java, ssl, apache-httpclient-4.x

I've seen plenty of examples of constructing an `SSLContext` that will accept all server certificates. For my test cases, I'm trying to do exactly the opposite and force the client to reject the server's certificate.

So I'm trying to create a `KeyStore` object that contains no root certificates, but when I try to use it I get an `InvalidAlgorithmParameterException` with the message 'the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty'. I have tried this:

```
KeyStore emptyTrustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
emptyTrustStore.load(null, null);
sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(emptyTrustStore, new TrustNoOneStrategy()).build();
```

and this:

```
KeyStore emptyTrustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
emptyTrustStore.setCertificateEntry("notreal", null);
sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(emptyTrustStore, new TrustNoOneStrategy()).build();
```

and (from an idea in a comment), this:

```
KeyStore emptyTrustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustNoOneStrategy()).build();
```

but none of these approaches solves the problem.

Obviously I could simply create a JKS file that contains a dummy root certificate and load that using the `SSLContexts.loadTrustMaterial(File)` method, but that seems really ugly: surely there is a way to do this just in code?

Comment: idk what happens but you can apparently do `loadTrustMaterial(null, ...`

Comment: @zapl: same behavior when you specify null. Updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: i wonder why you want to reject all certificates...

Comment: @nandsito One hopes it is for testing. Otherwise merely suicidal.

Comment: @nandsito I want to test the code that handles an attempt to connect to a server that has an untrusted certificate.

Comment: if the server offers an untrusted certificate, the handshake will fail with the default truststore or trustmanager just the same. You don't need to explicitly reject it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions. What I ended up with as a solution was to create a dummy root CA using OpenSSL, and including the PEM-formatted certificate in my test as a `String` value, building an `X509Certificate` from that `String`, installing it in a newly-created `KeyStore` object and then using that `KeyStore` as the trust store.

Since I created the certificate and then immediately deleted the private key once I had the certificate, I know that there can never be a server certificate actually signed by this dummy CA.

```
KeyStore dummyTrustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    try {
        dummyTrustStore.load(null, null);
        dummyTrustStore.setCertificateEntry("dummyroot", buildDummyCertificate());
    } catch (CertificateException | IOException e) {
        // handle exception
    }
sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(dummyTrustStore, new TrustNoOneStrategy()).build();
```

where the `buildDummyCertificate()` method is:

```
private X509Certificate buildDummyCertificate() throws CertificateException {
    CertificateFactory cFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(PEM_CERTIFICATE.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));
    return (X509Certificate) cFactory.generateCertificate(is);
}

private static final String PEM_CERTIFICATE = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n"
                                                  + "MIIEMDCCAxigAwIBAgI..."
                                                  ....
                                                  + "...n1xJLO3k=-----END CERTIFICATE-----";
```

One interesting wrinkle is that the newline character after `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` is required: without this the certificate creation fails with this error:

```
java.security.cert.CertificateException: Could not parse certificate: java.io.IOException: Incomplete data
at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificate(X509Factory.java:104)
at java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(CertificateFactory.java:339)
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```java
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s)
            throws CertificateException {
    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s)
            throws CertificateException {
        throw new CertificateException();
    }

    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return new X509Certificate[0];
    }
}}, null);
```

Note that the trust manager will throw an exception for every challenge.

You can see the context rejecting poor stackoverflow certificate:

```java
HttpsURLConnection connection =
        (HttpsURLConnection)
                new URL("https://stackoverflow.com/").openConnection();
connection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
connection.getResponseCode();
```

Comment: You don't need the TrustManager. You can use the default one along with an empty truststore.

Comment: @EJP i presume it is what you suggested in you answer. I tried that, and you are right in the sense that it will fail all TLS/SSL handshakes, but our answers differ in how they fail and in the scope of affected SSL contexts (the default one or a specifically created one)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create an `SSLContext` for this. Just point it to an empty truststore via the associated system property.

Comment: That won't work for the reason given in the Q; the default `X509TrustManagerImpl` (or more exactly its `PKIXValidator`) aborts if `trustAnchors` is empty

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I don't have the source code ready to hand but the whole idea of the question is for it not to work.

Comment: I wasn't clear enough in my question: this suggestion will certainly prevent the connection from succeeding, but what I missed from the question was that I want to have some tests that accept the certificate and some tests that reject it in the same test suite. So changing the system property is too blunt of an instrument for this use.

Comment: The abort case sends alert 80 internal_error, not any of the alerts JSSE would normally and correctly send for untrusted cert, and at least externally is not quite the same test.